# What is the derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{4-x}$

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=\sqrt{4-x}$, then is $$f^\prime (x)= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{4-x}}$$ or is $$f^\prime(x)= \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{4-x}}?$$ I am confused as to where the negative sign comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the power rule and chain rule, 
$$\left(\sqrt{4-x}\right)\prime = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{4-x}}\cdot (4-x)\prime \\ = \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{4-x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

It's your second answer.  The negative sign comes from applying chain rule (derivative of inner function, $4-x$).

Answer (score 1):

The negative sign comes from the chain rule.

$$f(x) = \sqrt{4 - x} \implies f'(x) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{4-x}} (4 - x)' = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{4-x}}$$